# Find value in array (Postgresql)

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, select

The following returns "**{3130,3135,2179,3186}**", type "**INTEGER[]**":

```
SELECT
array_agg(c) AS c
FROM
(
SELECT 3130::INTEGER AS c
UNION
SELECT 3135::INTEGER AS c
UNION
SELECT 2179::INTEGER AS c
UNION
SELECT 3186::INTEGER AS c
) AS v
```

If I try to find the number "3186" by directly converting the text to an integer array, it works just fine:

```
SELECT 3186::INTEGER = ANY
(
'{3130,3135,2179,3186}'::INTEGER[]
)
```

But if I try doing the same with the result from the first query, I get an "**operator does not exist: integer = integer[]**" error message:

```
SELECT 3186::INTEGER = ANY
(
    SELECT
    array_agg(c) AS c
    FROM
    (
    SELECT 3130::INTEGER AS c
    UNION
    SELECT 3135::INTEGER AS c
    UNION
    SELECT 2179::INTEGER AS c
    UNION
    SELECT 3186::INTEGER AS c
    ) AS v
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm Using PostgreSQL 9.5.3, PgAdmin 1.22.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could explicitly cast to `INTEGER[]`:

```
SELECT 3186::INTEGER = ANY(
(
    SELECT array_agg(c) AS c
    FROM (
       SELECT 3130::INTEGER AS c
       UNION
       SELECT 3135::INTEGER AS c
       UNION
       SELECT 2179::INTEGER AS c
       UNION
       SELECT 3186::INTEGER AS c
    ) AS v
)::INTEGER[]);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=43a0d6c19cfe93914d9b612ca21b8d67)**

Answer (score 2):

There are two forms of `ANY()`. In your query they are mixed.

If you want to use [`ANY (array expression):`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.28.16)

```
SELECT 3130 = ANY(
    ARRAY(
        SELECT 3130::INTEGER AS c
        UNION
        SELECT 3135::INTEGER AS c
        UNION
        SELECT 2179::INTEGER AS c
        UNION
        SELECT 3186::INTEGER AS c
    ) 
)
```

or

```
SELECT 3130 = ANY(array_agg(c))
FROM (
    SELECT 3130::INTEGER AS c
    UNION
    SELECT 3135::INTEGER AS c
    UNION
    SELECT 2179::INTEGER AS c
    UNION
    SELECT 3186::INTEGER AS c
    ) alias
```

If you want to use [`ANY (subquery):`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-ANY-SOME)

```
SELECT 3130 = ANY(
    SELECT 3130::INTEGER AS c
    UNION
    SELECT 3135::INTEGER AS c
    UNION
    SELECT 2179::INTEGER AS c
    UNION
    SELECT 3186::INTEGER AS c
)
```